# MediaSource and m4a audio

Tags: javascript, media-source

I am trying to make MediaSource work with m4a audio and yet had no luck with it.

I've tried to feed it to MS as is, using mime `'audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"'`. Then I tried to reencode it to `mp4` and then feed it to mp4box first to add headers. And then used it with mime `'video/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"'`. (`mp4a.40.2` is what `mp4info` shows, so it's real, not my fantasy)

None of this worked. On Chrome MS just closes itself firing no `sourceclose` events, on Firefox it does just nothing showing no errors.

I use the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>   </head>   <body>
    <video controls></video>
    <audio controls></audio>
    <script>
      // var video = document.querySelector('audio');
      var video = document.querySelector('video');

      // var assetURL = 'myfile.m4a'
      var assetURL = 'myfile.mp4'
      // var mimeCodec = 'audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"'
      var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"'

      if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
        var mediaSource = new MediaSource;
        console.log(mediaSource.readyState); // closed
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceclosed', function() {debugger; console.log('just closed')});
        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
      } else {
        console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
      }


      function sourceOpen (_) {
        console.log(this.readyState); // open
        var mediaSource = this;
        var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
        console.log(this.readyState); // open
        fetchAB(assetURL, function (buf) {
          sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function (_) {
            console.log(mediaSource.readyState); // suprise: it's closed
            console.log('before endOfStream')
            mediaSource.endOfStream(); // fails here
            console.log('before play')
            video.play();
            console.log(mediaSource.readyState); // ended
          });
          sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buf);
        });
        console.log(this.readyState); // open
      };

      function fetchAB (url, cb) {
        console.log(url);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open('get', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function () {
          cb(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.send();
      };
    </script>   </body> </html>
```

Should I reencode my `m4a` file in some other way? Should I just forget about it and use mp3?